# Why does Getting error missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my SQL query. I got a error missing right parenthesis but I  think there is some issue with interval.

```
select max(valdate) 
  from CORE_TOTEM.TOTEM_MONTHEND_COVERAGE
 where valdate<=sysdate 
   and valdate>= DATE_ADD(sysdate, INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused with `Oracle DB`, since there's no `sysdate` pseudocolumn in `MySQL` but `current_date` might be used instead as:

```
select max(valdate) 
  from CORE_TOTEM.TOTEM_MONTHEND_COVERAGE
 where valdate<=current_date 
   and valdate>= DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

**Edit:** Due to your last tagging, you should consider using the following one

(*since there's no function called `DATE_ADD` in Oracle whilst `MySQL DB` has*):

```
select max(valdate) 
  from CORE_TOTEM.TOTEM_MONTHEND_COVERAGE
 where valdate<= trunc(sysdate) 
   and valdate>= trunc(sysdate)-5;
```

or

```
select max(valdate) 
  from CORE_TOTEM.TOTEM_MONTHEND_COVERAGE
 where valdate between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate)-5;
```

Comment: Tried this also, but it gives me this error:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 23 Column: 76

Comment: @DeepaValecha since, you converted your tagging to Oracle from MySQL. Please have a look at my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no DATE_ADD function in Oracle. for add or substruct days from date just use(±) like sysdate-5 or sysdate+5.

```
select max(valdate) 
  from CORE_TOTEM.TOTEM_MONTHEND_COVERAGE
 where valdate<=sysdate 
   and valdate>= sysdate-5
```